# ASP.Net - The validation error inside update panel disappears after dropdown item change

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, updatepanel

I have a submit form inside a update panel. If a user click on the submit button without filling any value, the validation message is shown on all the required fields.

Now, when user select or change an item from the dropdown control then all the validation message disappears. The dropdown control have **AutoPostBack="true"**.

To resolve this I have tried to put all the dropdown control in one update panel and other controls in another panel but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this in your update panel:
`<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList ID Here" />
         </Triggers>
     <ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

OR

By using JavaScript Code:

`if (document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList ID.ClientID%>").value == "--SELECT--") {
                alert('Your Message Here');
                document.getElementById("<%=DropDownList ID.ClientID %>").focus();
                return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Validaton of the form manually after the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the DropDownList has completed.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "validateForm", "setTimeout(function () { Page_ClientValidate(); }, 25);", true);
}
```

If you use a `ValidationGroup`, you need to specify it in the function: `Page_ClientValidate('myGroup');`

The only downside to this is that it will trigger ALL validators, not just the ones that have been activated by the user above the DropDownList that performs the PostBack.